I can't delete an object in SwiftData
I've been developing a VisionOS app that allows you to search for new recipes directly from an API, and I would like to provide the ability to store the user's favorite meals. For that, I thought about using SwiftData and, by now, it's working pretty well. It stores the favorite meals, and if I reload the app, the favorite meal button loads well. However, for an unknown reason, I can't 'unlike' the meal. Can somebody help?
Here are the classes involved. When debugging I actually saw that it does enter the function but it doesn't delete anything. If my explanation isn't clear, I'll leave the repo link here. Other pieces of advice will be welcomed too!
Meal and MetaMeal struct
struct Meal: Codable,Hashable {
    let idMeal: String
    let strMeal: String
    let strInstructions: String
    let strMealThumb: String
    let strTags: String?
    let strYoutube: String
    let strIngredient1: String?
    let strIngredient2: String?
    let strIngredient3: String?
    let strIngredient4: String?
    let strIngredient5: String?
    let strIngredient6: String?
    let strIngredient7: String?
    let strIngredient8: String?
    let strIngredient9: String?
    let strIngredient10: String?
    let strIngredient11: String?
    let strIngredient12: String?
    let strIngredient13: String?
    let strIngredient14: String?
    let strIngredient15: String?
    let strIngredient16: String?
    let strIngredient17: String?
    let strIngredient18: String?
    let strIngredient19: String?
    let strIngredient20: String?
    let strMeasure1: String?
    let strMeasure2: String?
    let strMeasure3: String?
    let strMeasure4: String?
    let strMeasure5: String?
    let strMeasure6: String?
    let strMeasure7: String?
    let strMeasure8: String?
    let strMeasure9: String?
    let strMeasure10: String?
    let strMeasure11: String?
    let strMeasure12: String?
    let strMeasure13: String?
    let strMeasure14: String?
    let strMeasure15: String?
    let strMeasure16: String?
    let strMeasure17: String?
    let strMeasure18: String?
    let strMeasure19: String?
    let strMeasure20: String?
}


@Model
class MetaMeal {
    let meal:Meal
    init(meal: Meal) {
        self.meal = meal
    }
}

ViewModel
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Observable
final class SwiftDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: MetaMeal.self)
    var likedMeals: Set<Meal> = []
    
    @MainActor
    var modelContext: ModelContext {
        container.mainContext
    }
    
    @MainActor
        func getMeals() {
            likedMeals = []
            let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<MetaMeal>(predicate: nil, sortBy: [SortDescriptor<MetaMeal>(\.meal.strMeal)])
            let metaMeals: [MetaMeal] = try! modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
            likedMeals = Set(metaMeals.map { $0.meal })
        }

        @MainActor
        func handleMeal(metaMeal: MetaMeal, isHeartFilled: Bool) {
            isHeartFilled ? insert(metaMeal: metaMeal) : deleteMeal(metaMeal: metaMeal)
        }

        @MainActor
        func insert(metaMeal: MetaMeal) {
            modelContext.insert(metaMeal)
            getMeals()
            try? modelContext.save()
        }

        @MainActor
        func deleteMeal(metaMeal: MetaMeal) {
            modelContext.delete(metaMeal)
            getMeals()
            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    
    @MainActor
    func isMealFavorite(_ meal: Meal) -> Bool {
        return likedMeals.contains(meal)
    }

    }

View
struct MealDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openIngredientsWindow
    @State private var isHeartFilled = false
    @Environment(SwiftDataViewModel.self) var swiftDataViewModel
   
    var meal: Meal

    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            if let url = URL(string: meal.strMealThumb) {
                AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .success(let image):
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        Text("Error al cargar la imagen: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    case .empty:
                        ProgressView()
                    @unknown default:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
           
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Text(meal.strMeal)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white.gradient)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(.extraLargeTitle, design: .rounded))
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        isHeartFilled.toggle()
                        swiftDataViewModel.handleMeal(metaMeal: MetaMeal(meal: meal), isHeartFilled: isHeartFilled)
                        print(swiftDataViewModel.likedMeals.count)
                    }) {
                        Label("", systemImage: isHeartFilled ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        
                    }.symbolEffect(.bounce.down, value: isHeartFilled)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        openIngredientsWindow(id: "Ingredients", value: meal)
                    }) {
                        Label("", systemImage: "carrot")
                    }

                    
                    Button(action: {
                        openIngredientsWindow(id: "Instructions", value: meal)
                    }) {
                        Label("", systemImage: "play.circle")
                    }.padding()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        openIngredientsWindow(id: "ImageZoomed", value: meal)
                    }) {
                        Label("", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    
                }
          
            }
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
            .padding()
            .offset(x: 0, y: 200)
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            isHeartFilled = swiftDataViewModel.isMealFavorite(meal)
        }
    }
}


swiftDataViewModel.handleMeal(metaMeal: MetaMeal(meal: meal), isHeartFilled: isHeartFilled), here you always create a new MetaMeal no matter if it exists already  or not. Then you either insert it (possibly creating a duplicate?) or you delete a new object that isn't even stored yet. I think (I didn't check all the code) you have a problem with handling a single source of truth and don't know what exists in your local storage. Is this why likedMeals is a Set and not an Array? You need to use the idMeal property of Meal so you can properly identify a Meal/MetaMeal object. continued...

Maybe you should also add it to MetaMeal as well to easier find existing Meal objects. And pass a Meal and not a MetaMeal to the handleMeal function and create the MetaMeal object inside the function when you now you really need to insert a new object.

Note, you should have @Observable final class SwiftDataViewModel {...}, remove the ObservableObject.
See Managing model data in your app

@JoakimDanielson I used the Set to check if a specific meal is liked or not. The problem is that when storing the data it doesn't create duplicates as I'm using the Set and it doesn't allows so, but the problem is that when deleting a Meal, the amount of objects stored doesn't change and I'd like to know why

Like I wrote, you are deleting an object that is new and not inserted yet into the database so whatever you have in the database remains unchanged. You have a Set yes but that is a set of Meal and not MealData which is quite different. You might very well store two copies of the same Meal but in different MealData objects without knowing it.

Try adding "id" and assign "unique" in your swifdata model

@Model
class MetaMeal {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: UUID
    let meal:Meal
    init(id: UUID = UUID.init(), meal: Meal) {
        self.id = id
        self.meal = meal
    }
}


It's not working. I've pasted it in my code and I got Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer) error :(

You can make it simpler by accessing MetaMeal directly from the view. There is no need to add another layer of abstraction, through the use of view model.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Meal {
    
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
class MetaMeal {
    
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: UUID?
    var meal: Meal
    
    init(id: UUID?, meal: Meal) {
        self.id = id
        self.meal = meal
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Delete") {
                // get access to the meta meal
                //let metaMeal =
                // context.delete(metaMeal)
                
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: MetaMeal.self)
}

If there is any logic that must be checked before deleting the MetaMeal then you can isolate that logic right inside the model class.
@Model
class MetaMeal {
    
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: UUID?
    var meal: Meal
    
    init(id: UUID?, meal: Meal) {
        self.id = id
        self.meal = meal
    }
    
    func delete(context: ModelContext) {
        // insert logic here
        
        context.delete(self)
    }
}

